# Backbone JS event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

I'm having trouble getting backbone events working. I simply want to simulate a form submission and get an alert, but I can't seem to get there...

My markup is as follows:

```
<form method="post" id="userSignIn">       
   <label>Email</label> 
   <input type = "text" name = "useremail" value = "" id="userEmail"> 

   <br />

   <label>Pass</label>
   <input type = "password" name = "userpass" value = "" id="userPassword">

   <br /><input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
</form>
```

My JS

```
var events = _.clone(Backbone.Events);

var SigninModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'http://localhost/api/app/User.php',
});

var SignInCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: SigninModel
})

var SigninView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'submit #userSignIn': 'signIn'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        console.log('Sign in view initialized');
    },

    signIn: function(e) {
        alert("Your username is" + $('#userSignIn #userEmail'));
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var signInCollection = new SignInCollection();
    new SigninView({ el: $('#userSignIn'), collection: signInCollection });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone.View.events will only look for events triggered by DOM elements that are part of the view's element (or a child of that element).  Ideally you'd render this HTML via the render method on the view but an alternate approach would be to call setElement from inside SignInView.initialize

Comment: Can you show me how to do this in code exactly? My actual intention is to then do an ajax call on sign in to the URL in SigninModel() which passes the #userEmail.val() and #userPassword.val() as the "data" parameters.